# Did any Achronim Write Books Comparing Arabic to Hebrew?

Tags: hebrew, language, sources-mekorot

Did any achronim write books comparing Arabic to Hebrew?

Comment: Is the person asking the question still around? Should the question be changed? There are a number of Geonim that wrote books on the topic, and some rishonim discuss it lightly, but Achronim?

Answer (score 3):

Several rishonim draw comparisons between Arabic an Hebrew. But earlier, even the Tannaim used  foreign languages to explain difficult Hebrew words. See, for example, Bavli Rosh Hashana 26a ([here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=26&format=text), the six last lines).
The early Hebrew grammarians used Arabic (their native language) in constructing the formal grammar of Hebrew, borrowing the concept of triliteral roots (and of using פעל as the base word for verb patterns) and other ideas from Arabic. Rav Saadia Gaon used Arabic to explicate difficult Hebrew words in his commentaries on Tanakh. For a treatment of this in particular, see Professor R. Steiner's new book on Rasag, "Biblical translation in the making." Also, the Arukh (by Natan b. Yechiel of Rome) frequently compares Aramaic words to Arabic and other languages. However, strictly speaking, no, I don't believe there are any books by a rishon or acharon that are solely on the similarities between Hebrew and Arabic.

Comment: +1 I saw that book and it looked interesting. Do you know where Arabic grammarians got their system from? Or how old it is?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any Achronim, but some Rishonim (such as Rashi and the Ramban) discuss similarities.

Comment: Where do they discuss the similiarities?

Comment: Search rashi for the words loshon Yishmaeli

Comment: -1, this does not answer the question being asked whatsoever.

Comment: @AdamMosheh yes it does. The question asks on Jewish literature associating Arabic with Hebrew, and the answer provided just that +1.

Answer (score 0):

Rabbeinu SaAdiyah Jaon compared the 2 languages in his commentary on Sefer YasSirah. He is a Jaon not an Acharon though.

Comment: Saadia himself would never have pronounced it Jaon. He thought 'J' was corrupt and it should really be 'G' like the English word 'Girl'.

Comment: I know what he said, and teimonim pronounce the kuf as a guf, like in english girl, I am still learning how to pronounce the chreemal, it just doesn't work out for me. I am leaning towards that over a jimmal, however I then have guf and gimmal which sound the same.

Comment: Then you can pronounce the ק as a throaty K sound, like Iraqis and Adeni Temanim do, and as does [MSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qof#Arabic_q.C4.81f).

Comment: I know what the yahudim in bovel pronounce it as and I know what that small group of teimonim do, however it is not plausible for one group of teimon be right compared to all of teimon who prnounce it as a j.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob - Actually, the Jimal pronunciation of the gimal daghushah is really from the dialect spoken in the central city/region of Yemen, Ssan'aa. The majority of Temanim (before the aliyoth to EY) pronounced the "Gimal" and hard "Quf" like like in the Massri dialect of Arabic (which the most widely-spoken dialect of Arabic in the world). However, since the Torah scholars who set up the schools and batei keneseth in EY after the aliyoth were Ssan`aani, the Jimal was proliferated into the eventual majority. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist yes the teimonim from sanaa pronounce is as jeem while those from adhaan and near by areas like sharaab pronounce is as geem and qof, however that is also the same with the arabic of those regions. the arabs pronounce the jeem as geem and gof as qof in those areas. it is in no way right to say that "majority" of teimonim pronounce it s geem and qof. the masri dialect is widely spoke now. modern standard arabic is the masri dialect but hence the name modern stanndard arabic. and even in msa people pronounce the jeem and not geem. only northern masrim pronounce it as geem.

Comment: @Maimonist not to mention that msa is not used in day to day between countrymen. they speak their own dialect of arabic and only use msa to speak to other country men. also i have no clue where you got the idea that jeem was made standard for all teimonim in aras yisroeil because the adhaneem still say geem and qof and those from saana still say jeem.

Comment: I am aware of all that, but the findings of linguistic anthropology is that in Arabic the gim was original and it was with the spread of Quraanic dialect that used a jim that it changed. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist actually the scholarly opinion for the spread of the jeem throughout the arab world is after the quran in the 7th century because of the badawi invasion. none city dwellers like the badawis spoke their own dialect which influenced others to speak that way once they got into power. it is said that muhammad might have said geem. however the jeem is much older and goes back to babylon even from where the teimonim come from. they didnt come from aras yisroeil but from boval. in boval they already had the jeem and it is even purported that our prophets spoke this way as well maybe.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob - Huh. I will have to look further into this. I have had discussions between to pillars on this subject, one a traditional Temani Rav and the other a scholar of history. The former said as you did that jim was older. He even said that Rasag was too late of a source because the Temanim are older and so is their use of the jim. The latter, however, told me as I said before. Can you give me a source where I can study this further?

Comment: @Maimonist its obvious rasaj zl is too late. its obviously teimonim(and all those around rasaj zl) that pronounced with a jeem didnt start when rasaj zl was writing the book. its obviously much older. rasaj zl is 9-10th century while scholars say it is already from the 7th. https://www.academia.edu/8770050/Al-Jallad._2014._A%E1%B9%A2-%E1%B9%A2%C4%80DU_LLAT%C4%AA_KA-S-S%C4%AAN_EVIDENCE_FOR_AN_AFFRICATED_%E1%B9%A2%C4%80D_IN_SIBAWAYH go to page 54 second to bottom paragraph and down for scholarly opinion

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob - At first I was excited, but then what I read in the link you posted seems to argue for the antiquity of the "gim" and not "jim". Help me out if you think I missed something? Also, check out this discussion: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/egyptian-arabic-yemeni-arabic-%D8%AC-pronounced-as-hard-g.264201/

Comment: @Maimonist yes thats what i said. the geem is older yet people still said jeem. still looking for the paper. cant find it in my 1500 pdf collection